# Rails using TinyMCE content_css does not link properly in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce

Hi so I am trying to use tinymce and have everything working in debug mode. Here is the code in my js.erb file:

```
function tinymce_load(){
  tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea.mceEditor",
    plugins: [
     "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
     "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen autoresize",
     "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste textcolor"
    ],
    menu : "core",
    toolbar1: "bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect",
    toolbar2: "cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist outdent indent blockquote | undo redo | link unlink anchor image media code | preview | forecolor backcolor",
    toolbar_items_size: 'small',
    content_css : "<%= asset_path 'website.css' %>"
  });
}
```

My problem is when I run in production mode it cannot find the asset website.css. I think this is because when I am compiling my assets it compiles them into one css file. Is there a way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `asset_path`

and also check for `/` (slash)

something like that

```
content_css : "<%=asset_path '/website.css' %>"
```

Answer (score 0):

So to get it to work I just added the whole application css:

```
content_css : "<%=asset_path 'application.css' %>"
```